# Can't use ngIf and ngFor in same template correctly. Angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-template, angular-ng-if

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedPlayer; else infoText">
      <div *ngFor="let playerEL of players">
          [playersTEST]="playerEL"
          (playerWasSelected)="onPlayerSelected(playerEL)">
      </div>

    </ng-container>

  </app-stats>
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? (like an error message), because there a several strange things in your code

Comment: Can't bind to 'playersTEST' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

Comment: can you past the code of the directive with the playersTEST input?

Comment: Are you using a playerTEST directive ? What is your goal with this code ?

Comment: There's a typo at `<div *ngFor="let playerEL of players">`, the last `>` shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 3):

Little Typo in your code. You need to reformat your DIV code correctly as given below

```
<div *ngFor="let playerEL of players"
          [playersTEST]="playerEL"
          (playerWasSelected)="onPlayerSelected(playerEL)">
      </div>
```

and then implement your IF ELSE as suggested by @windmaomao.

Answer (score 2):

They do have some conflicts in Angular2+. Angular2 doesn't support more than one structural directive on the same element. So you can split them into two elements.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedPlayer else infoText">
    <div *ngFor="let playerEL of players"></div>
</ng-container>
<ng-container #infoText>
    No records.
</ng-container>
```

`ng-container` can avoid create extra div, otherwise you can use `ng-template`.

Comment: He doesn't have more than one structural directive on one element.

Comment: You are right, I didn't answer directly to his answer. But I kinda know where he's heading towards :)

Comment: He's only kinda heading towards a redundant `>` at `players">` ;-)

Comment: Yeah, that's true, i understand better now, that might be too much.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your directive hadn't been instantiated or recognized. Check the directive selector or if you add it in the module, or if you add the directive's module to the component module.